# CentOS 6.5 kernel panic when running a perf process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, perf

I'm working on making continuous profiling on running process, so I set a crontab on server. It periodically runs a python script which exec perf subprocess collecting perf data from a daemon process started by supervise

The perf command I use is like this:

```
perf record -p {target process} -e cycles:u -a -q -g -- sleep {some time}
```

Everything goes on well except for the running process terminates.We sometimes need to update the target process executable file and restart the process with `svc -t`. The operation may lead to a kernel panic and we have to reboot the machine

My server's distribution version is `CentOS release 6.5 (Final)` and linux release version is `2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64`

The core dump log and backtrace is shown as below

```
general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
CPU 1
Modules linked in: AliSecGuard(U) AliSecProcFilter64(U) tcp_diag inet_diag joydev microcode virtio_net virtio_balloon shpchp i2c_piix4 i2c_core ext4 jbd2 mbcache virtio_blk virtio_console virtio_pci virtio_ring virtio pata_acpi ata_generic ata_piix dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]

Pid: 22748, comm: server Not tainted 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 Alibaba Cloud Alibaba Cloud ECS
RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8111db57>]  [<ffffffff8111db57>] ring_buffer_put+0x77/0xf0
RSP: 0018:ffff8801afadbda8  EFLAGS: 00010006
RAX: ffff880416d81e60 RBX: ffff8803d335f000 RCX: 63496d6165727473
RDX: 676e697274736f5f RSI: 0000000000000003 RDI: ffff880416d81c00
RBP: ffff8801afadbdd8 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00000000ffffffff
R10: 00000000ffffffff R11: dead000000200200 R12: ffff8803d335f058
R13: 676e697274736cff R14: ffff8803d335f060 R15: 0000000000000202
FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff880028240000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
CR2: 0000000004264d70 CR3: 0000000001a8d000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Process gameserver (pid: 22748, threadinfo ffff8801afad8000, task ffff8803a19cd520)
Stack:
 ffff8801afadbdf8 ffff8803a1b03800 ffff8804138bf78c ffff8804138bf790
<d> ffff88001a9fb800 ffff8804182a1c80 ffff8801afadbdf8 ffffffff8111e377
<d> ffff8804138bf790 ffff8803a1b03800 ffff8801afadbe28 ffffffff8111fe72
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8111e377>] free_event+0x37/0x170
 [<ffffffff8111fe72>] perf_event_release_kernel+0x72/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8111ff49>] put_event+0x99/0xd0
 [<ffffffff81123a65>] __perf_event_exit_task+0xf5/0x150
 [<ffffffff81123c91>] perf_event_exit_task+0x1d1/0x210
 [<ffffffff8107ca24>] do_exit+0x1e4/0x870
 [<ffffffff8107d1b7>] sys_exit+0x17/0x20
 [<ffffffff8100b0d2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Code: ff ff 4c 39 f0 48 8b 97 60 02 00 00 74 5f 4c 8d aa a0 fd ff ff eb 08 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 89 cd 48 8b 8f 68 02 00 00 be 03 00 00 00 <48> 89 4a 08 48 89 11 31 c9 48 89 87 60 02 00 00 48 89 87 68 02
RIP  [<ffffffff8111db57>] ring_buffer_put+0x77/0xf0
 RSP <ffff8801afadbda8>
```

```
PID: 22748  TASK: ffff8803a19cd520  CPU: 1   COMMAND: "server"
 #0 [ffff8801afadbb30] machine_kexec at ffffffff8103d1fb
 #1 [ffff8801afadbb90] crash_kexec at ffffffff810cc882
 #2 [ffff8801afadbc60] oops_end at ffffffff8153da20
 #3 [ffff8801afadbc90] die at ffffffff81010fab
 #4 [ffff8801afadbcc0] do_general_protection at ffffffff8153d512
 #5 [ffff8801afadbcf0] general_protection at ffffffff8153cce5
    [exception RIP: ring_buffer_put+119]
    RIP: ffffffff8111db57  RSP: ffff8801afadbda8  RFLAGS: 00010006
    RAX: ffff880416d81e60  RBX: ffff8803d335f000  RCX: 63496d6165727473
    RDX: 676e697274736f5f  RSI: 0000000000000003  RDI: ffff880416d81c00
    RBP: ffff8801afadbdd8   R8: 0000000000000001   R9: 00000000ffffffff
    R10: 00000000ffffffff  R11: dead000000200200  R12: ffff8803d335f058
    R13: 676e697274736cff  R14: ffff8803d335f060  R15: 0000000000000202
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
 #6 [ffff8801afadbda0] ring_buffer_put at ffffffff8111db20
 #7 [ffff8801afadbde0] free_event at ffffffff8111e377
 #8 [ffff8801afadbe00] perf_event_release_kernel at ffffffff8111fe72
 #9 [ffff8801afadbe30] put_event at ffffffff8111ff49
#10 [ffff8801afadbe60] __perf_event_exit_task at ffffffff81123a65
#11 [ffff8801afadbe90] perf_event_exit_task at ffffffff81123c91
#12 [ffff8801afadbef0] do_exit at ffffffff8107ca24
#13 [ffff8801afadbf70] sys_exit at ffffffff8107d1b7
#14 [ffff8801afadbf80] system_call_fastpath at ffffffff8100b0d2
    RIP: 0000003026207c41  RSP: 00007fe4d1e56e50  RFLAGS: 00000246
    RAX: 000000000000003c  RBX: ffffffff8100b0d2  RCX: 0000000000000001
    RDX: 0000000000000004  RSI: 00000000009fb000  RDI: 0000000000000000
    RBP: 0000000000000000   R8: 000000000598f280   R9: 00000000000058dc
    R10: 00007fe4d259f3ac  R11: 0000000000000246  R12: ffffffff8107d1b7
    R13: ffff8801afadbf78  R14: 0000000000000003  R15: 0000000000000000
    ORIG_RAX: 000000000000003c  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

The attached process's thread exit causes the kernel panic and the panic cannot be reproduced every time, so I suppose this may be kind of a race condition bug in kernel?

BTW, the perf process doesn't exit after attached process terminates on my server (because of old version I guess), so perf will continue to work until I interrupt it. I'm not sure whether this can affect the target process exit

Comment: perf has to be built with the kernel, so make sure you are using perf-2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: well, I got it by `yum install` and the version is perf-2.6.32-754.33.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: vault.centos.com has the version matching you kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in that old kernel version; user-space `perf` shouldn't be able to panic the kernel.  Either Linux 2.6.32 was buggy, or maybe CentOS's patch backporting (or the patches themselves) introduced a bug that only happens when perf is active.

I don't think it's plausible to fix this on your own, unless you want to really dig into kernel debugging, so your options are

1. update your kernel (from CentOS if available, otherwise you'll have to find another source for kernels, e.g. mainline).
2. update your distro to one that uses newer kernels.  (And newer everything else).
3. stop using `perf`.
4. Maybe not possible: find a different set of perf options that doesn't trigger this crash.  (Be careful testing, whatever bug is causing this could possibly manifest in other ways like memory corruption, possibly leading to corrupting file data before it's written out to disk if you get unlucky with writing through a wild pointer.  The bug *might* not have that possible failure mode, but you can't be certain until you've found it.)

Comment: It's not a bug. As noted above, pert doesn't match the kernel version.

Comment: @stark: Unprivileged user-space shouldn't be able to panic the kernel, even with `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid = 0` or even `-1`.  The `perf` package is just user-space code, not kernel modules.  `perf` uses PAPI system calls like `perf_event_open` to get the kernel to program counters and read results.  (I think this is how has always worked.)